# How many else if statements should we use?

Tags: php, ajax, coding-style

I have a PHP file `ajax.php` where i always send my ajax to. There are about 50 else if statements in the code. I always pass a POST Parameter `cmd` to my `ajax.php` file and check if the variable is set and execute different code depending on the variable content.

I was wondering if i should rather split my `ajax.php` to multiple files to reduce the amount of `else if` statements and increase performance. But how many `else if` are we recommended to use and does it have a big impact on performance if we use e.g. 10000?

Comment: The biggest impact would be on _maintaining_ that code

Comment: ^ definitely agree.. another thing is that switch would be better than having a lot of else if...

Comment: I don't see an advantage on using `switch`

Comment: Read some article about single responsibility principle. For example: http://www.sitepoint.com/the-single-responsibility-principle/ This code is unmaintable

Comment: @AlexAndrei 10K `if`s or 10k `case`s is still an awful mess

Comment: if you have about 50 if/else statements in your code,  you need to revise your approach completely.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think performance would be a problem with 50 or 100  different commands. But what i would suggest is to use switch case and functions, like this

```
$cmd = $_POST['cmd'];

switch ($cmd){
    case "command1":
        fnCommand1();
        break;
    case "command2":
        fnCommand2();
        break;
}

function fnCommand1(){
    //do command 1
}

function fnCommand2(){
    //do command 2
}
```

It would be easier to read and more manageable in case you decide to split it into files,

Comment: Now you have 10000 `case`s and 10000 functions

Comment: Is it bad to have so many functions? Or should we write the code directly in the switch statement?

Comment: it is better to have functions instead of writing everything in the switch cases, it just easier to mantain for the programmers, to PHP it almost doesn't matter, it is just more organized, you have 1 switch, 1 "small" block of code handling the $cmd, calling the function(s) you need in every case.  and then you have as many functions as you need .  you could even have the switch in 1 PHP file, and then group the functions in different files by category, and "include" those files in the switch file and always POST to the switch file. also, do you really need 10000 functions? optimize functions!

Answer (score 1):

You can use key value pattern in php. Make a array with your post paramaters as key and other as s values.
Whenever the paramater will come to `ajax.php` check for the key using array_key_exist()
[Array key value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) and
[Array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

i think that is barely insane to write 10k elseif by yourself, i would prefer to crack my head and find a valid algorithm, or use a `switch` statement instead.

Btw, try always to avoid this kind of situation, doesn't really matter if is a single file or 1000 files, the processing time will always be the same

Answer (score 0):

Separating file can not benefit performance but human readable and maintainable.

If your code is something like:

```
if($_POST["cmd"]=="a"){
//case a
}else if($_POST["cmd"]=="a"){
//case b
```

For performance, you can change it to switch case.
But if statement optimization always not performance-critical.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesnt have performance issues with some many lines but people do. Maybe you can read the code because you remember it now. But if your somebody joins  your team he will be lost and probably wont join because of that. Or if you came back to this script after a year would you be able to read it, add or delete something?

Every script or class schould do one thing or work with one entity. There are many approaches how to write better code.

[single responsibilty principle](http://www.sitepoint.com/the-single-responsibility-principle/)

[Object oriented Programming](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762)

and many more